# c++ : how can I call a method in main function without creating an object

Tags: c++

I have the following class:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    float x_;
    float y_;
    float z_;

    Vector(float x, float y, float z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}
    float scalar(Vector a, Vector b);
};
```

and the following method:

```
float Vector::scalar(Vector a, Vector b)
{
  return a.x_ * b.x_ + a.y_ * b.y_ + a.z_ * b.z_;
}
```

now I am initializing `Vector a` and `Vector b` in main function:

```
int main()
{
  Vector a = Vector(1,2,3);
  Vector b = Vector(4,5,6);

  float result;
  // how can I call the scalar() method and save the return value in result

  return 0;
}
```

But now I am wondering how to call the scalar() method. I've tried to declare scalar() static but it did not work.

Comment: Why is it a member function if you don't want to manipulate an object's (`this`) state? All the data you need is accessible without membership.

Comment: Make it `static` and call with `Vector::scalar(a, b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create your method as a static method. It would have the same effect as namespacing your method with the class name.

```
class Vector
{
public:
    float x_;
    float y_;
    float z_;

    Vector(float x, float y, float z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}
    static float scalar(Vector a, Vector b);
};
```

Which you can call the following way in your main:

```
int main()
{
  Vector a = Vector(1,2,3);
  Vector b = Vector(4,5,6);

  float result = Vector::scalar(a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unlike some other languages, C++ lets you have functions that are not members of a class. You can just define the function outside the Vector, and then call it without an object prefix.

```
class Vector
{
public:
    float x_;
    float y_;
    float z_;

    Vector(float x, float y, float z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}
};

float scalar(Vector a, Vector b)
{
  return a.x_ * b.x_ + a.y_ * b.y_ + a.z_ * b.z_;
}

int main()
{
  Vector a(1,2,3);
  Vector b(4,5,6);

  float result = scalar(a, b);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define scalar as static and call it as a static method:

```
class Vector
{
    ...

    static float scalar(Vector a, Vector b);
};
```

and

```
auto result = Vector::scalar(a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
float Vector::scalar(const Vector& other)
{
  return x_ * other.x_ + y_ * other.y_ + z_ * other.z_;
}

int main()
{
  Vector a(1,2,3);
  Vector b(4,5,6);

  float result = a.scalar(b);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trivially close  ...

Since the ctor and dtor are 'trivial', you can simply instantiate a dummy Vector, and use that dummy's scalar method.

But if you can't bring yourself to trivialize the cost (of the ctor / dtor) or you know you will be incrementally growing their behaviour, you can also make use of either of the already existing Vector's. Note that the **method Vector::scalar() does nothing to the local data**.  Thus, no 'static' required.  No code changes required.

```
int main()
{
  Vector a = Vector(1,2,3);
  Vector b = Vector(4,5,6);

  // instantiate a dumy vector
  float result1 = Vector(0, 0, 0).scalar(a,b);  // dummy Vector

  // use an existing vector
  float result2 = a.scalar(a,b);  // method scalar does not modify self.

  std::cout << "\n\n  " << result1 << "  " << result2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Both results are same, i.e. 32

Comment: I call 'scalar()' a utility function ... but it is unexpected for a method to not modify local attributes.  And this is a good reason to use a 'static' modifier as suggested in several other answers.

Comment: There is no need to create dummy objects for this solution, a simple member function or static member function solution is enough, and is cleaner. In fact the static member function example provided by @Ra'Jiska is a common utility function solution.

Comment: @Curg  I think my answer says there is no need to 'modify the assignment'.  Perhaps I paid too much attention to "I have the following ... [class and method]".  He did not claim authorship.  I still think it is a homework. I had a prof with a sideways look at the resources, and he would give the 'outside-the-box' solutions extra credit.  And yet the OP did accept the 'static' mod, so perhaps I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer provided 2 choices that avoided changing any of the class code you have.  Rationale: An activity that most professional programmers get involved  with (ahem, 'assigned'), is a) adding functionality, and b) responding to a change in requirements.  And of course, there is c) the 'fix' to coding errors.   Your efforts will be smaller (and thus sooner complete, and thus better received) if you minimize impact to existing code.

This answer suggests adding 2 lines to your existing class Vector,

1. add the default ctor  (Note - the default ctor and dtor do nothing)
2. add  operator()

These two 1 liner additions allow you to use the class as a functor.

From Google, C++ functor:

> A functor (or function object) is a C++ class that acts like a
>   function. Functors are called using the same old function call syntax.
>   To create a functor, we create a object that overloads the operator().
>
> Functors in C++ - GeeksforGeeks
>   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functors-in-cpp/

---

```
class Vector
{
public:

   // ... as above


   // functor style access:
   Vector() = default;                   // default ctor
   float operator()(Vector a, Vector b) { return scalar(a,b); } // operator()

}; // class Vector
```

> how to call the scalar() method?

Through the functor:

```
int main()
{
  Vector a = Vector(1,2,3);
  Vector b = Vector(4,5,6);

  float result = Vector()(a,b);

  std::cout << "\n\n  " << result 
            <<   "      even more convenient: " << Vector()(a, b) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```